# Spring DirtiesContext

Tags: spring, junit

I am now using Spring and JUnit, and I use @DirtiesContext to get my test cases independent of each other, but I get OutOfMemoryError each time I run my test case.

Is there any that I can config the memory use of @DritiesContext ?

Thank you!